# Kotlin flow : Are there situations when a flow is not the right solution?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

Kotlin flow is a relatively new tool added to Kotlin. However, I am not clear about when a Kotlin flow is not the right design choice.
An example I can think of is that of search. Say you have a movie database (local or cloud) in an Android app, you are creating a feature where you can search for movie names/actors/year of release etc. Is this a good candidate for flow?
It does not sound like it because each search query is just one request and one response. Maybe if there are multiple pages, it could be considered a stream. If there is no paging involved, then is it a good candidate for flow?
We could simply use launch {} get the data and move on. Is there advantage of using flow?

Please let me know your thoughts.

Comment: Don't use flow for single results, use simple suspend functions. Sometimes this is also true if the result is a list (if elements are not provided asynchronously nor as a stream). If you have pagination in your API and you want to abstract it away, then yes a flow could be useful

Comment: Flows are what they are: asynchronous streams of items with backpressure. If we don't need multiple results, suspend functions make more sense. If we don't need asynchronous support, then sequence/iterator is much easier to use. If we need a generic tool to synchronize/communicate coroutines, flows are not very useful - use channels.

Comment: Depends on how you display the result. For example: with view model you can create a flow that will collect your current search query (stored in mutable state flow) and transform it into data to display that is ready to be collected by the view layer. Using launch is doable but you have to self manage jobs (eg. cancel ongoing query when you start new one, ensure there's no race with returning result from them) which might be a bit of a headache.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer : A lot.

Long answer : Flow is a stream. If you're planning to return (or in this case, emit) multiple result from the function at different point in time, then use flow.

I would advise against using stream (flow) when you are only returning a result once. If you think that you need to return more than once in the **future**, the refactor the code in the future, not now.

For search, personally I use flow for search result, and I have even done so recently. An example of this is if we have caching strategy, such as

```
return cache first if available -> then get from remote -> save the result from remote -> return result AGAIN from remote.
```

we are doing return twice in that example, so it would be a good idea to use stream, in this case flow. So it doesn't have to be paging, just be creative. A great way to realize that you actually need flow is by doing TDD. While create the test cases, you will realize whether or not you need a stream for doing something.

Comment: In your example, you have a potential to return the search result twice, once from the cache and once from the remote. But it's not exactly a constant flow of events, like say in a chat application. It's either once or twice. Is it still OK to use flow? 
Is it because of the fact that flow provides methods for mapping, merging, filtering of the data as it is produced?

Comment: I believe that it should be fine to use flow this way, as this allows me to put caching logic in Repository instead of ViewModel. Without using stream, I would be forced to write the logic in ViewModel to get repository's local, then get repository's remote BUT if you see the guidelines from Android, the data source should be handled in Repository which means handling it in ViewModel is not a great idea. Flow's mapping functionality just makes things easier in general for handling multiple data source and transforming data on the fly.